# PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA1 for passwords -- examples in C?

Tags: c, cryptography, password-encryption, hmacsha1

I've been looking for about a week to find an example of something in C that would work as the 'turn this password into properly hashed form for storage' using either the BSAFE or openssl crypto libraries, generating decent salt and doing a arguably adequate number of rounds.

Does anyone know of an example from which to crib?  I'm lazy enough to prefer not to have to figure it all out myself the hard way, as this is a small (but key) part of another project.

thanks
-dB

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood your question, but it seemed you knew what you wanted crypto-wise, you had identified the candidate libraries that could be used, but were "lazy enough" to want someone to put the code together for you. These days, not enough effort isn't a valid reason to close, but I may still have voted to close this as "too broad" or "unclear what you're asking".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will demo how to use openssl api to generate the hash.

```
#include <openssl/evp.h>

// more ITERATIONs, more secure. But you should consider the performance on your target machine
ITERATION = 512000; 

// this will be the result of PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA1  
int SHA1_LEN = 20;
unsigned char* out = (unsigned char*)calloc(SHA1_LEN, sizeof(unsigned char));

int SALT_LEN = 5;
unsigned char* salt = (unsigned char*)calloc(SALT_LEN, sizeof(unsigned char));
RAND_bytes(salt, SALT_LEN);

pwd = ""; /*your password here */
PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1(pwd, strlen(pwd), salt_value, SALT_LEN, ITERATION, SHA1_LEN, out);
```

Comment: Thanks, the example I'm looking for is the source to openSSL's PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1.